# User Meta Data in a Sortable Table

Tags: users, user-meta, table

I have created a template that stores extra user data in to user meta, for example: how fast they row 100m, how fast they run 5km.

I'd like to now display this data within a table, thats searchable and sortable. 
I'm guessing the best way to do this is a plugin? 
I can't seem to find a plugin for user meta data?
Any help would be great. I've started to create a PHP template, but not sure this is the best way to start....
OR something like this: 
https://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/